# Why different p-value when using pairs() or a contrast()?

Tags: anova, p-value

Why do I not get the same p-value when comparing the marginal means for 3rd and 2nd person using the pairs() or contrast() function? (see code below)

[image]

Comment: Note that, although this is couched in terms of R code, this is actually a statistical question, primarily about formulating contrasts, and actually, *p*-value adjustments.

Comment: Note that for the *third_second* contrast, and this comparison from *pairs()*, that the *t*-value, *SE*, and *df* are essentially the same.  Did you try with *adjust="none"* ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes i have noticed this - yet the P values are so different. Yes, I have tried without the adjustment and the p values are still different, not sure why?

Comment: Did you explicitly call *adjust="none"* ?

Comment: Ah thank you so much! When explicitly calling adjust = "none" - they give the same p-value. So why do I need the adjustment for the contrast but not for the pairs?

Comment: The amount of the *p*-value adjustment, if you will, from the unadjusted value, is based on the number of *p*-values  in the list of *p*-values being adjusted, so the result changes depending on what's in that list.  It should be the case that if you had the same contrasts in *pairs()* and in *contrast()* with the same correction method, that the results would come out the same.

Comment: I see, this makes sense, thank you so much! So is this why ideally you should run as few contrasts as possible? As otherwise the adjustment will make the p-values higher than if you ran fewer contrasts?

Comment: Would you use the Holm adjustment when comparing more than just a pair?

Comment: You can investigate the different adjustments available in the software when adjusting either the pairwise comparisons or multiple contrasts.  If you don't have good reasons to choose one adjustment or another, it's probably fine to use the default (in either case, which are different) or use "none" if that fits your purpose better.